# React native Stylesheet.absoluteFillObject not covering tab bar to make in-app message

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I got a `react-native` app and would like to implement some sort of in-app messaging functionality.

The in-app message has to pop over the entire application and can be clicked or closed.

I'm creating a component with a render like this:

```js
// InAppMessage.jsx

render() {
    if (this.state.open) { // if the in-app message needs to be seen
      return (
          <View style={{ zIndex: 1000, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, borderColor: 'yellow', borderWidth: 2 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: Colors.semiTransparent, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.navigate('ProfileScreen')}> // just a fixed example
                <View style={{ width: 150, height: 150, backgroundColor: 'red' }}></View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
      );
    } else return null
  }
```

I then add the in-app component in any screen like this:

```
// RandomAppScreen.jsx

import InAppMessage from './InAppMessage.jsx'

[...]

render (
    <View>
        <InAppMessage />
        [other specific screen stuff]
    </View>
)
```

You can see the result here:
[image]

I'm using `react-navigation` v3 with 20+ screens in stacks, tabs and switch navigators.

The InAppMessage component does not goes over the bottom tab like I would like, why?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` is just replacement for `position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0` so if the parent view has `position: relative` the overlay will be only on the view but not on the entire screen. Maybe the solution will be to put an overlay `View` on the app's root and show / hide it from the screens.

Comment: @MoshFeu that was the initial idea but I need to use the navigation prop from `react-navigation` to navigate so I need to be inside

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it!

Fortunately I had the navigation state in the redux store. God save redux.

So the hierarchy was the following:

```
App  
--> Redux  
    --> ReactNavigation
```

Now is

```
App  
--> Redux  
    --> ReactNavigation
    --> InAppMessage
```

I can connect the new InAppMessage to the store and dispatch actions like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Colors } from '../../Themes';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

class InAppMessageOverlay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.navigate.bind(this);
    this.state = { open: true };
  }

  navigate(screen) {
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: screen }))
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.open) {
      console.log(this.props);
      return (
          <View style={{ zIndex: 1000, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, borderColor: 'yellow', borderWidth: 2 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: Colors.semiTransparent, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.navigate('ProfileScreen')}>
                <View style={{ width: 150, height: 150, backgroundColor: 'red' }}></View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
      );
    } else return null
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InAppMessageOverlay)
```

I will use the redux state and not the component state but I was too exited to share this

Picture related
[image]